# CGAL kruskal isolated edge

Tags: cgal, delaunay, kruskals-algorithm

I have created a finite Delaunay graph and launched kruskal MST on it, and it seems that in one of my test, I have an isolated edge in the MST (not connected to the others).
Is that supposed to happen?
How can I prevent that from happening, having all my edges connected to at least on other edge of the graph.

Thanks!

Comment: Please put your code and the data set here: https://gist.github.com/  so that we can try to reproduce/understand/explain or fix.

Comment: Hi, you can find the code/data/explanations there : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8f80ccd614e8337b431f0a2e4c294d1#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: noone has an idea?

Comment: @risinde: You could try my package at https://christofidesheuristic.codeplex.com/ or post your graph?!